# Excel roundings not summing properly

Tags: excel, sum

I have a excel sheet with a few formulas like this:

```
A1,A2,A3= 0.13,1.25,2.21

A4: =(A1*A2)     =0.16 ( 2 decimal points)
A5: =(A2*A3)     =2.76 ( 2 decimal points)
A6: =SUM(A4;A5)  =2.93 ( 2 decimal points )
```

**And i want to show 0.16+2.76=2.92**

well, there's my problem in bold. i want to add the values from the cells, not the formuls result. How can i do that ? Thank you

Comment: `.13 * 1.25 = .1625` and `1.25 * 2.21 = 2.7625` therefore `.1625 + 2.7625 = 2.925` which when rounded to two decimals is `2.93`

Comment: i know how to use math ! EHEH but i don't want "proper" math now. I need it that way . Thanks

Comment: If you will need to round the A4 and A5 before adding together.  `=ROUND(A1*A2,2)` to get what you want.

Comment: Or you can round down the last `=ROUNDDOWN(SUM(A4;A5);2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner i can't use rounddown cause it's not always something like 2.925 . Using round works properly ! Thank you. U can give an answer to close the question :)

Comment: Feel free to choose any of the answers below.  They guessed better as to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you're working with money which is why you need this.

One way to resolve this is to use `=ROUND(A1*A2, 2)` etc. and base your subsequent calculations from that.

Do be aware though that you will still occasionally get spurious results due to Excel using a 64 bit IEEE754 floating point double to represent numbers. (Although it does have some *extremely* clever circumvention techniques - see how it evaluates 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 - it will not resolve every possible oddity). If you're building an accounting-style sheet you are best off working in pence, and dividing the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Round the values before you sum, ie:

```
=ROUND(A1*A2,2) 
=ROUND(A2*A3,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your formulas with the ROUND function:

```
=ROUND(A1*A2,2)
```

This will give you 0.16 as opposed to 0.163. Do this for each of your calculations and you'll only be calculating everything to two decimal places. Although I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: i can't use rounddown cause it's not always something like 2.925 . Using round works properly ! Thank you

Comment: There's no harm in editing this answer to correct it.